# Accessing StoreKit receipts directly from a server

Tags: ios, storekit

I'm building an iOS app, which provides a service which our website already provides. It's a subscription based service, where all features are enabled when you're subscribed. To get people to sign up for regular payments on the app, it seems like I'll have to go through Apple's in app purchasing API, with auto-renewing subscriptions. That's fine, but the problem is the service users will purchase through the app must also be available on the site. But reading through walkthroughs and the developer guide, it looks like the only way to process transactions is through the app itself, which then can be set up to pass the info to the server. But then I'm imagining this scenario:

User purchases a subscription on the iOS app, goes back and forth between using the site and the iOS app. On the day the user is to be charged, and the days after, they're using just the website, for whatever reason. The server doesn't know they've been billed though, and so features are disabled. In order for the server to find out the user has been billed by Apple, the user has to open the app on their iphone or ipad and sync it with both Apple and my server.

Is there any way for my server to ping Apple directly and get information about the purchases made for my app for a given user? I haven't been able to find anything; the two suggested layouts, with or without server, both use the iOS app as the sole communicator with Apple, aside from having the server verify that information is valid. If it's not possible for the server to get this information first hand, what other possible solution could there be?

1. Try to not use Apple's built in payment system, and risk getting rejected (with the app duplicating a service that's been available for years online, do we no longer have to use their in app purchasing system anyway?)
2. If a user is paying through Apple, have the server give them a generous buffer between expected payment dates and when features are disabled (makes the problem happen less frequently but doesn't solve it)
3. When their account seems expired to the server but it doesn't expect that, email the user a message saying they have to open the app or else their account will not be credited for time purchased (seems like a strange and not really great thing to have to ask a user to do in order to use the service)

This is about all I've been able to think up so far. Anyone have any advice on these solutions, or know of others, or know who I could talk to to try and figure this out?

Comment: A little too much info here. Can you winnow it a little? Otherwise [Programmers.SE] maybe better

Comment: Thanks for the link! I've gone and signed up. Next time I'll be mindful of the different kinds of questions. I'll leave it as it is, since it's now been answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can check on the status of a user's account from your server.  There are a few caveats:

- First and foremost, Auto-Renewing Subscriptions are reserved for periodicals such as magazines and newspapers.  If your app doesn't resemble those, Apple may reject it (as they did mine) and request that you use Non-Renewing Subscriptions (read: Manually-Renewing Subscriptions).
- Second: This scenario would require you to store all receipts that you receive on the app, on your server.
- Finally: I don't know how your username/password system works, but the user would have to login with the same credentials on your app as they do on your website.

Here's how you check the status of a user's account:  Store at least one receipt per user on your server.  When you want to check the status, follow Apple's procedure for [Verifying App Store Receipts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html). Send them that one receipt and they'll respond with the latest receipt and the expiration date. Now you'll know, at any given moment, if a person's account is current or not.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that answers my question! That system will work fine. Re: being rejected, that is also a concern. Looking at the Apple doc though they say: "Subscriptions provide access to content or services on an extended basis. For example, your application might offer monthly access to financial information or to an online game portal." I read this with hope, but I've also heard what you say from other sources, too. I guess the only thing for it is to submit the app and see. Points 2 and 3 are already how it's being built.

Comment: Yes about the Apple doc quote, but I think that statement applies to both subscription types.  I'm not saying that they won't let you use subscriptions at all, I'm just saying that they might insist you use Non-Renewing instead of Auto-Renewing type. And that may be a blessing. Auto-Renewing subscriptions can be a headache: you can't cancel a subscription on your end, you can't tell if a user has 'auto' turned on until it renews, etc.  And with Non-Renewing subscriptions you can manually extend a user's subscription as a bonus, since you calculate the expiration date yourself.

Comment: Hi Guys, The link posted earlier seems to have been removed by Apple.